# How to remember user settings

Tags: php, cookies, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to use a cookie to 'remember' user settings.

I have a menubar in my back-end which the user can narrow or widen. If the user narrows the menubar, a cookie is set and if the user widens the menubar the cookie should be removed.

Now, if i narrow the menubar on page 1 and widen it again, everything is fine. But if i narrow the menubar on page 1 and go to page 2 to widen it again, the cookie wont be removed and instead a new cookie with the same name will be made.

I would like to know how to use a Laravel Cookie to remember this setting ( i use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) now ) if that is possible. Else i really would like to receive suggestions on how or what to do to remember user settings.

I've heard cookies can work and session can work, but apparently i can't make it work or so.. Suggestion appreciated!

Comment: What is your current code used to set a cookie? It sounds like it isn't being applied to the whole domain, only the specific page.

Comment: @Jake `docCookies.setItem('menubar','test', 900, '/admin/members/*');` This is what i use to make the cookie. Cookie is set on /admin/members. Should be ok right?

Comment: I'd recommend setting it to just "/". It avoids troubleshooting confusing problems later on and may fix it.

Comment: You directed me in the right way @Jake! Though, the cookie is set on admin/members, but if a user wants to go to an other/next page the URL become i.e. admin/members/modules. If i make the path 'admin/members/' i can remove the cookie on i.e. 'admin/members/modules' but then i can't remove it on 'admin/members', I dont know if it is possible, but is the following possible? "admin/*/*/" ? Making the * function as wildcards.. even if the path is just 2 levels deep or so.. And BTW: the '/' as path did not work at all.

Comment: Well, I know you can't use wildcards in normal HTTP cookies, so I suspect that's one of the issues. Even without the wildcard, it will apply to all pages under that folder.

Comment: Well.. somehow it doesnt apply to all pages under that folder.. If i do '/admin/' it will only be useable on '/admin/members' but if i do '/admin/members/' it will only be useable on '/admin/members/modules' or '/admin/members/videos' and not on 'admin/members' itself.. Really weird this...

Comment: Tried a different Cookie 'framework' [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) and this actually works.. Better then [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)

Answer (score -1):

I found out that somehow when using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) cookie 'framework', it doesnt really work that well. When i played a bit with [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) cookie 'framework' it actually WORKS like a charm